# Не отображается float

Tags: c#

Привет.

Принимаю по UART число float 0x00606a46 (15000)

Склеиваю и отображаю так:

```
float MeasuredTimeDir1OK = ((float)((InMessage[1] << 24 | InMessage[2] << 16 | InMessage[3] << 8 | InMessage[4] << 0))); 
label5.Text = "t1: " + MeasuredTimeDir1OK.ToString("0.0000") + " мкс";
```

где 
InMessage[1] = 0x00;
InMessage[2] = 0x60;
InMessage[3] = 0x6A;
InMessage[4] = 0x46;

на label5.Text вижу: 6318662,0000 (должно быть 15000,0000)

Что сделал не так?

Comment: вы байты не в том порядке читаете. Вы же месяц назад задавали практически такой же вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Вы склеиваете байты руками. Не делайте так, иначе вы ССЗБ. У вас порядок байтов противоположен правильному. Кроме того, cast в C# работает не так, как вы думаете (причём даже в C он работает не так, вы хотите `reinterpret_cast` из C++).

Попробуйте

```
var MeasuredTimeDir1OK = BitConverter.ToSingle(InMessage, 1);
```

Comment: ССЗБ +1 Да не делайте так!

Comment: а что такое CP,? Самый Страшный Злодей Бармалей?

Comment: @DreamChild 
Сам себе злобный Буратино же =)

Comment: @VladD не слышал)

Comment: Спасибо! работает